# Not able to fetch relative x-path with class, name attribute

Tags: xpath

I am facing issue with relative x-path. I am able to fetch x-path with 'id' attribute only, not with class, name. I have unchecked 'generate absolute x-path'. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

xpath example:

```html
//*[@name=’name_value’]
```

or if has a long name and you want to select by a part of that name

```html
//*[contains(@name, ’name_value’)]
```

Same for class,change @name with @class